# Root file system reported as being 100% without adding any file

Tags: linux, ext4, fstab, root-filesystem

I have a 35G mount as my root file system, and until now, it was reporting 1% usage.

I was using an SD card for my storage and today I got a new one. I'm mounting my `/swap` partition on that, so I decided to partition the new one with a swap and a "normal" one.

First I created an NTFS partition in case I want to use the card in Windows. I had problems, so I tried FAT, and ultimately I went to `ext4`.

In the process, I was modifying my `/etc/fstab` file and restarting, but when I got the card working, now my root file system reports being used at `100%`!!! without me changing anything there.

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5    35G   33G     0 100% /
...
```

And `df -i`:

```
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5    2.2M   20K  2.2M    1% /
...
```

I thought maybe this is because `fsck`, and I did

```
touch /forcefsck && reboot
```

But that didn't solve the issue. I didn't change anything in my root file system.

Line in `fstab` for that:

```
UUID=<uuid>      /              ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
...
```

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: What does `sudo du -hcx --max-depth=1 /` return?

Comment: Thank you @ajgringo619 for your answer, the issue was coming from something else that I missed. I provided the details as the answer because I think the issue was specific to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out during my mounting/umounting/rebooting etc., something happened.

I was mounting the SD card on `/media`, and I'm not sure why, but when I finished with the SD card setup, apparently the `/media` was created as a directory and not a mount, so it was that directory taking up space.

I didn't notice that it's not actually my mount and a directory , so I deleted the directory and mounted the SD card on `/mount` and the issue is solved